# why is ...at syscall using a different dirfd than the previously opened one?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Using `LD_PRELOAD` I am printing all the file descriptors that are opened, but then the `...at` syscalls use different file descriptors.  Why?

The simplest possible example:

Here is my library `foobar.c` - it intercepts all the `open...` calls and prints file descriptors, and it prints arguments to calls to `unlinkat`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    int fd = ((int (*) (const char*, int, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"))(pathname, flags);
    printf("open pathname %s fd %d\n", pathname, fd);
    return fd;  
}

int open64(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    int fd = ((int (*) (const char*, int, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open64"))(pathname, flags);
    printf("open64 pathname %s fd %d\n", pathname, fd);
    return fd;  
}

int openat(int dirfd, const char* pathname, int flags, ...) {
    int fd = ((int (*) (int, const char*, int, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat"))(dirfd, pathname, flags);
    printf("openat pathname %s fd %d\n", pathname, fd);
    return fd;
}    

int unlinkat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags) {
    printf("unlinkat dirfd %d pathname %s\n", dirfd, pathname); 
    return ((int (*) (int, const char*, int))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "unlinkat"))(dirfd, pathname, flags);
}
```

I did not include the `dup` intercepts to keep it simple, they are not called.

Now notice the library is working fine, I catch all the file descriptors opened, they are all equal to 3, however, the opened file descriptor relative to which `unlinkat` is called, is 4. Why??

```
/tmp>mkdir -p dir/dir1
/tmp>gcc -shared  -fPIC -ldl foobar.c -o foobar.so
/tmp>LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/foobar.so rm -rf dir
openat pathname dir fd 3
openat pathname dir1 fd 3
unlinkat dirfd 4 pathname dir1
unlinkat dirfd -100 pathname dir
```

Comment: @MatteoItalia that was a good guess, thank you, I implemented that, but, there were no `dup...` calls present

Comment: Side note: when intercept calls of `open` and friends, process 3rd parameter `mode` *unconditionally*. Failing to pass this parameter in case of O_CREATE may break observable application.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes of course, but, in this case it was not needed, and I wanted the simplest possible example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[mitalia@mitalia /tmp]$ mkdir -p dir/dir1
[mitalia@mitalia /tmp]$ strace rm -rf dir
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "-rf", "dir"], [/* 76 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1538000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4c779a2000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=211009, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 211009, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4c7796e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4c773bd000
mprotect(0x7f4c77578000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4c77777000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7f4c77777000
mmap(0x7f4c7777d000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4c7777d000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4c7796d000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4c7796b000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4c7796b740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4c77777000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f4c779a4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f4c7796e000, 211009)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1538000
brk(0x1559000)                          = 0x1559000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5766672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5766672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4c76e3d000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "dir", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "dir", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 72
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "dir", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 72
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(4, "dir1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "dir1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "dir1", AT_REMOVEDIR)       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "dir", AT_REMOVEDIR) = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

On my system, the file descriptor 4 is the one returned by `fcntl` called with `F_DUPFD`, which is a close relative of `dup2`; I expect something similar happening on yours too.

In general, if you want to monitor file descriptors creations you have to monitor also file descriptors *duplication* functions (`dup`, `dup2`, `dup3`, `fcntl` with `F_DUPFD` and maybe others that I don't know).

Also, keep in mind that the `LD_PRELOAD` trick hooks only C library functions, applications are still free to perform "raw" syscalls (`int 0x80` on x86, `sysenter` on x86_64 and whatever on other platforms) without you noticing. The most reliable way to monitor all this stuff reliably is to use the (horrible) `ptrace` interface (the `PTRACE_SYSCALL` request should be your friend here), which, incidentally, is how `strace` is implemented.

Comment: thank you!  I did not know about `F_DUPFD` that is basically the answer to the question.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: neither did I, I noticed it in the `strace` output just for the suggestive name. =)